# Ossec fields to Oracle DB

Tags: logging, ossec

I would like some recommendations for the following problem.
I use Ossec for log analysis. What I want, is after extracting the fields
to save them in an Oracle database.

For example, if I have this line

> IP:(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)@(\w+): (forcefield \w+); (.*)

I want $1 go to Ip tables, $2 to host, $3 to msg ... etc

For the moment I am considering to execute a script when I have a  match, but 
I looking for a better approach if possible.

cheers

Comment: This seems a good way to me tbh

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this is possible within ossec, but you can do it with [nxlog](http://nxlog.org) (disclaimer: I'm affiliated with the project). It can write the fields to database using the om_dbi module.